# Sound on mouseover, stop on mouseout

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am working on a project where a sound plays when you mouseover an image and stops playing on mouseout. I want it to start over each time and there has to be multiple images on each page. I am looking for the most efficient way to make this code work. Here is the sample page: http://inventivewebdesign.com/audio-img/sound.html

Code:

```
<body>
    <script>
        function PlaySound(soundobj) {
            var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);
            thissound.play();
        }

        function StopSound(soundobj) {
            var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);
            thissound.pause();
            thissound.currentTime = 0;
        }
   </script>


<a onmouseover="PlaySound('violin')" onmouseout="StopSound('violin')"><img src="violin.png"></a>

<a onmouseover="PlaySound('xy')" onmouseout="StopSound('xy')"><img src="xy.png" width="300px" height="300px"></a>

<a onmouseover="PlaySound('piccolo')" onmouseout="StopSound('piccolo')"><img src="piccolo.png"></a>

    <audio id='piccolo' src='piccolo.wav'/>
    <audio id='violin' src='violin.mp3'/>
    <audio id='xy' src='xy.mp3'/>

</body>
```

This all works. My only question is how to make the code more efficient. 
I saw that I should be able to do something like this:

```
<audio>
    <source id='piccolo' src='piccolo.wav'>
    <source id='violin' src='violin.mp3'>
    <source id='xy' src='xy.mp3'>
</audio>
```

But it doesn't work. Is the first set of code above the best way to do it?

Comment: `I saw that I should be able to` where? multiple `source` for `audio` is a list of alternative sources for the one `audio`

Comment: As @JaromandaX stated, the second code snippet you provided serves a different purpose and will not make your code more efficient. You will be fine if you leave it the way it is.

Comment: Thanks! That's all I needed to know!

Answer (score 0):

Good question @MattM. I would simply add a function to create new instances of the audio hovers, making make it easier to implement more sounds without code repetition.

```
function newHover(e){
     var audio = new Audio(); // creates audio element
     audio.src = e.audio; // the audios location
     var image = new Image(); //creates the image element
     image.src = e.image; // the images location
     image.className = e.title; // applies the name of the instrument to both elements
     audio.className = e.title;
     image.addEventListener("mouseover", PlaySound); // listens for mouse movement
     image.addEventListener("mouseout", StopSound);
     document.body.appendChild(audio); // appends the audio and image to the body of the document
     document.body.appendChild(image);
}
```

That way, the below code block is unnecessary:

```
<a onmouseover="PlaySound('violin')" onmouseout="StopSound('violin')">
     <img src="violin.png">
</a>

<a onmouseover="PlaySound('xy')" onmouseout="StopSound('xy')">
     <img src="xy.png" width="300px" height="300px">
</a>

<a onmouseover="PlaySound('piccolo')" onmouseout="StopSound('piccolo')">
     <img src="piccolo.png">
</a>

<audio id='piccolo' src='piccolo.wav'/>
<audio id='violin' src='violin.mp3'/>
<audio id='xy' src='xy.mp3'/>
```

Implement this in your code, none of the HTML above is needed in this solution.

(Note: getElementById was changed to querySelector in PlaySound and PauseSound functions)

```js
function PlaySound(e) {
    var thissound = document.querySelector("audio." + e.target.className);
    thissound.play();
}
function StopSound(e) {
    var thissound = document.querySelector("audio." + e.target.className);
    thissound.pause();
    thissound.currentTime = 0;
}
function newHover(e){
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = e.audio;
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = e.image;
    image.className = e.title;
    audio.className = e.title;
    image.addEventListener("mouseover", PlaySound);
    image.addEventListener("mouseout", StopSound);
    document.body.appendChild(audio);
    document.body.appendChild(image);
}


window.onload = function(){
    newHover({
        audio: "http://inventivewebdesign.com/audio-img/piccolo.wav", // Path to the audio file (the src property of audio tag)
        image: "http://inventivewebdesign.com/audio-img/piccolo.png", // Path to the image file (the src property of the image tag)
        title: "piccolo" // The name of the instrument (applied as a className to both the image and the audio elements)
    });
    newHover({
        audio: "http://inventivewebdesign.com/audio-img/xy.mp3",
        image: "http://inventivewebdesign.com/audio-img/xy.png",
        title: "xy"
    });
    newHover({
        audio: "http://inventivewebdesign.com/audio-img/violin.mp3",
        image: "http://inventivewebdesign.com/audio-img/violin.png",
        title: "violin"
    });
}
```

```css
a{
  position: absolute;
}
img{
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<a>Hover over the images!</a>
</body>
```

In conclusion, your solution works effectively, However it would make it much easier for you to have a function to create the audio hovers for you.

I took a look at inventivewebdesign.com, very nice website there!

---

EDIT>>>>>>>>>>>>

Note - I have tested the script in Firefox and Chrome. It should work fine.

For clarification on how to use the function:

To insert an image. Call the newHover function Like so:

```
    newHover({
       audio: /*audio src here eg. music.wav*/,
       image: /*image src here eg. picture.png*/,
       title: /*title here eg. violin / xylophone / piccolo*/
    });
```

The images will be inserted into the document. You can then apply css styles or do what ever else you want to them.

Comment: This is interesting, I will look at it tomorrow. I did notice when I did Run Code Snippet I got a Script error.

Comment: How do I set the images in different locations? Your code just says: <body>
<a>Hover over the images!</a>
</body> but I don't see how to put images in. I will need to put images in columns with text blocks next to them. Final product will be similar to this: http://kids.renophil.com/strings/